# SEO Help - Using Rich Snippets

Tags: seo, php, rich-snippets

I launched my web comics website late November of last year and would like to improve its SEO.

Go Daddy provides Search Engine Visibility assistance... so I'm trying to understand that.

Right now, my SEO sucks. My goal is to have the search look like The Oatmeal's:

[image]

But currently looks like this:

[image]

So... my questions are:

1) How do I control the descriptive text under my URL. Currently it says "use of this website signifies your agreement to my terms and conditions", which is certainly not something I want to show up in search.

2) I've created a "Rich Snippet" which GoDaddy says I need to attach to each of my blog posts. I built my website from scratch using PHP, and did not use an existing framework. So, the way I'm displaying images is pulling rows from a MYSQL database... once someone clicks on the comic thumbnail, it displays the associated (by ID) full size comic on the "view comic" template. So I'm not sure where I should put this generated Rich Snippet code. Should I just put it in the  section?

```
<link rel="author" href="https://plus.google.com/u/0/104687106959620241243/about" />
```

Comment: I just checked your webpage, and google has updated the description tag and title! Yay!

Comment: @guisasso lol finally! it's been forever! Thanks for letting me know haha

Comment: No problem man, I'm glad it worked out!

Comment: @guisasso btw I'm redesigning my site because it's too "1990's". Check out my new designs and let me know what you think! http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/31704/how-to-not-make-my-website-have-a-1990s-look

Comment: I like it man. B is my favorite. Its just a matter of playing with gradients and shadows and it'll look great. I would incorporate a third color, a dark navy blue type of color and I think a pattern for the background would make it look great. Take a look at this, it might be helpful: http://www.stripegenerator.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 - This goes in the `<head>` section of your website:

`<meta content="Here you describe your website, and that's what appears on search engines" name="description" />`

2 - *Edit: Anywhere before or after the article you just wrote. [here](http://www.highrankings.com/rel-author-323)

Comment: Hi, I already have <meta name="description" content="Hitting Trees with Sticks is dedicated to sharing high quality original satirical comics with the world."> in the head section of my website- The search result doesn't seem to be picking that up though...

Comment: @Growler It doesn't update automatically like that. Give it some time.

Comment: @Growler google yahoo for example and look at their source code, you'll find the description as my answer there.

Comment: But I've add that meta content description up for several weeks now and it keeps grabbing my Copyright disclaimer from the footer.

Comment: @Growler You did not mention anywhere in the question that you had that in your the website already. It was my understanding that you didn't know about it altogether. You have to be very specific. Now, when did you add that to your website? Was it there since launch?

Comment: It's been there since early December (Site was launched mid-November). Sorry for not mentioning that.

Comment: @Growler Ok, so it may be something else, but looking at your code I don't think so. Do you have a google webmaster tools account? If not, create one, go to "health->Fetch as google". Fetch your home page, wait a couple of seconds and click on submit url. Additionally, submit an updated sitemap. Like I said before, often it takes a while for these thing to be updated. Months sometimes. One last question, was the title of your website when launched HTwS?

Comment: Okay, I'll give that a shot. And yes, I recently changed the title from HTwS to something more descriptive: <title>Comics and Artwork - Hitting Trees with Sticks</title>

Comment: @Growler Then that's your answer right there! It is not displaying the updated changes just yet. =]

Comment: I know. I changed the title recently, but had the meta description tags updated for a while now.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7007/discussion-between-guisasso-and-growler)